# Sorting a jagged array by second column

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sorting, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged array and I need to sort it by the column "2":

example: array[x][2]

What I have is about 64 where the "x" is and in the second column (where the "2" is) I have 4 different options, but I need to sort by the second option.

Comment: Could you give an example of what array holds?

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson Why does it matter, so long as they're comparable?

Comment: Keep in mind that arrays are zero indexed, so `[2]` is the *third* item in the array, not the second.  `[1]` is the second item in the array.

Comment: @Servy Because I, for one, think something smells about having jagged arrays sorted by column 2, when maybe you're encoding what should be properties on a class as values in an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `OrderBy`:

```
array = array.OrderBy(inner => inner[2]).ToArray();
```

If it's important to use an in place sort then you can use `Array.Sort`:

```
Array.Sort(array, (first, second) => 
    string.Compare(first[2], second[2]));
```